# How do I upgrade packer on an aws ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, packer

I have an existing installation of packer 1.0.0 on my ec2 instance which i want to upgrade to 1.2.2. How do i upgrade packer to this version. If uninstalling and re installing is the only option, what is the way to uninstall packer. The output of command ***which packer*** on my ec2 instance is the following ***/usr/local/packer/latest/packer***

Comment: Packer is a single binary executable, so you should be able to download 1.2.2, unpack it, and then move it over the previous install. Are you asking how to execute commands to download, unzip, and move files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Packer is delivered as a statical linked single file binary. Just download, unpack, and replace `/usr/local/packer/latest/packer` (that's probably a symbolic link to `/usr/local/packer/1.0.0/packer` or something similar).